# Why app context cause memory leak in manual dependency container?

Tags: android

I make manual di using class AppContainer

```
internal class AppContainer private constructor(context: Context) {

        companion object {
            private var instance: AppContainer? = null
    
            fun getInstance(context: Context): AppContainer {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = AppContainer(context.applicationContext)
                }
                return instance!!
            }
        }
    
        val resourceProvider: ResourceProvider by lazy { provideResourceProvider(context = context.applicationContext) }
..............
    
    }
```

In all creation places I use app context, but it's cause memory leak. Why? Can I fix it without Kotin/Dagger?

Comment: How do you know it's a memory leak? Also note that application context is a poor choice for e.g. accessing resources but that's not the issue here.

Comment: AFAIK application context cannot change, so it doesn't count as a leak. What tool are you using to detect leak? It seems like a false positive.

Comment: i use leakcanary

Comment: In some places (Fragment for example) i use different context, but always get context.applicationContext. Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

I has found reason. ViewHolder context

```
companion object {
    fun onCreate(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        playerController: PlayerController,
        playerActions: PlayerActions
    ): VideoViewHolder {
        return VideoViewHolder(
            VideoItemBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            ),
            playerController,
            playerActions
        )
    }
}
```

I replaced parent.context to parent.context.applicationContext

Answer (score -1):

By annotating context with **@ApplicationContext** provided by Hilt, we don't need to create a provider for the application context.

Sample usage

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class ProductionModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAppDatabase(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): AppDatabase {
        return Room
            .databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase::class.java, AppDatabase.DB_NAME)
            .build()
    }
}
```

The scope of the AppContainer is only within your onCreate function, so once onCreate executed, your "your object" object is no longer needed and subject to garbage collection.

Comment: Is it possible without Dagger/Koin/Hilt?

Comment: It will work if you're sure it's a singleton.

Comment: I'm sure that it's work, but we are not using di frameworks. It will require rewriting our project.

Comment: According to the activity lifecycle, a director may be required. Where you use it, you should not neglect to kill it in the onDestroy method. Lifecycle management is an important part. From what I understand from your code you have installed Singleton, but that doesn't mean the garbage collector will definitely clean it up.

Comment: In particular you should be careful when dealing with anything that deals with the GUI that requires a Context. For example, if you pass the application Context into the LayoutInflater you will get an Exception. Generally speaking, your approach is excellent: it's good practice to use an Activity's Context within that Activity, and the Application Context when passing a context beyond the scope of an Activity to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Also, as an alternative to your pattern you can use the shortcut of calling getApplicationContext() on a Context object (such as an Activity) to get the Application Context.

Comment: I create this AppContainer in Views and Services and always pass context.applictionContext. Maybe is Services reason? Because service live more than app?

Comment: It can be used throughout the lifecycle of the services.

Comment: Hilt is "built on top of Dagger", something that the question explicitly excludes. Therefore: Not an answer.

Comment: but it can be used. Proposal. and it shouldn't be hard